# Time limits for Salat [Hanafi School]

Tags: salat

I know the starting time of *Fajr* and its ending time.

Starting time of *Zuhr* is also from mid of day. But When it ends?

Is it till *Asar*?
If it is so then what time of *Asar*?
The time specified by *Hanafi* School or *Shafi* School? (The *Shafi Asar* time is almost one hour before *Hanafi*'s).

Also what is end time of *Asar*? Till sunset or some time before it?
And if I say that I can see the sun is setting and some part of it is not visible, then at that time can I offer *Asar*?

Same queries about *Magrib* and *Isha*.